# How can I add a hover effect over Tkinter notebook tab?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add a hover effect over Notebook tabs. I used this method:

```py
def hover(widget, on_entrance, on_exit, entrance_fg, exit_fg):
    widget.bind("<Enter>", func=lambda e: widget.config(
                bg=on_entrance, fg=entrance_fg))
    widget.bind("<Leave>", func=lambda e: widget.config(
                bg=on_exit, fg=exit_fg))
```

It is not showing any error, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hover(your_widget, on_entrance='your_color', on_exit='your_color, entrance_fg='your_color', exxit_fg='your_color')
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work with Notebook tabs

Answer (score 0):

I try the same idea and finally I get it using the library https://pypi.org/project/tkinter-tooltip/

You have to declare in your notebook a class with the type ToolTip

I change the code a little from the original in the library, only because you can't change the message

```
def change_msg(self, new_msg):
        self.msg = new_msg
```

And in the notebook I create an event

```
self.bind('<Motion>', self.show_tooltip)
```

And a method named show_tooltip

```
def show_tooltip(self, event):
        if (event.y > 1 and event.y <= 22):
            try:
                self.tooltip.change_msg((str(self.tab(int(event.widget.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))))['text'])))
            except:
                pass
```

This method only change the name, but it always show the tab name. The if conditional is for enter when you are in the notebook tab site.

It's not perfect but it works, I hope it helps